# How to skip html headings and find number with regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, skip, strip-tags

I want to find NUMBER, but skip H1 , H2 , H3 and so on.. (all possible HTML heading variants)

Example 1:

```
<div>Today is good day. I got<h3>3<span> lotto tickets</span></h3></div>
```

Example 2:

```
I want to buy lotto tickets. <h1>Maybe 10 is enough</h1>
```

Example 3:

```
I want to buy lotto tickets. <h1>4 or 5</h1> is enough.
```

I have this code:

```
lotto tickets\D{0,15}(\d+\,\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

But every time i get numbers from HTML tag.. `<h3>` (3) , `<h1>` (1).
How i can skip them?

In **example 1** i should get nothing

In **example 2** i should get number **10**

In **example 3** i should get number **4**

(Numbers can be with **.** or **,** example: 2.5)

Comment: 6 years old  and still relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: This will make sure the digit isn't preceded by <h: `(?<!<h)\d+`.  Though it doesn't check if it is a fully formed header tag.

Comment: shouldnt example 1 return 3 ?? I see a 3 after `h3` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those instances where perhaps regex isn't being used correctly.

Yes, you could it just with regex, but a easier way to do it (as well as being faster to run), would be to run strip_tags() on your string first to get rid of all the HTML tags, and then just do a standard regex for the numbers.

```
$string = "<h3>This is post number 10</h3>";
$cleanString = strip_tags($string);
preg_match("%\b[0-9]+\b%",$cleanString,$number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following regex:

```
<h[1-6]>[^\d\<]*(\d+)[^\<]+<\/h[1-6]>
```